# Is a dictionary of philosophy necessary for reading Schopenhauer?

Tags: schopenhauer

Is a dictionary of philosophy necessary for reading Schopenhauer? I heard that he refused to use jargon and tried to write very clear.

Comment: It depends on how many words you already know, but he is generally accessible. It may help to know something of Kant. Did you try reading Schopenhauer?

Comment: This may help you:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Fourfold_Root_of_the_Principle_of_Sufficient_Reason

Comment: i'd say a good dictionary is probably enough. It is for most philosophers, and saves a lot of time.

Comment: Is a normal dictionary enough (not a philosophy one)? E.g. The Oxford American Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read the book on its self.

If there are some unknown words, try to look it up on [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/).

Me as a beginner in the philosophical literature, it helps a lot.

But you have to always count with the fact, that there might be some words, that do not officially exist or are a little bit different in the context of what you are reading.

The summary is, you will find most of the words there, but not all of them.

Comment: So you suggest me to use a simple english dictionary, not a philosophy one?

Comment: @PopularăSălaj I suggest that you might want to try the web dictionary, which is free and contains the same content as their philosophy one. It is not only a simple dictionary because it contains the content of all their printed dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend on the technical side:

Historical Dictionary of Schopenhauer's Philosophy (Historical Dictionaries of Religions, Philosophies, and Movements Series)
David E. Cartwright
ISBN 10: 0810853248 / ISBN 13: 9780810853249
Published by Scarecrow Press, 2004

Easily available in US & UK. The Oxford English Dictionary in any of its versions should be adequate on the non-technical side.